# Cron job to run rmmod not executing at reboot

Tags: bash, debian, shell, cron, proxmox

This is on Proxmox VE 7.3 with Debian 11. I ran `crontab -e`, added `@reboot /home/onboot.sh` to the file, saved it, ensured cron is running with `systemctl enable cron.service`and verified it's running at boot with `systemctl status cron.service`.

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-08 17:16:52 EST; 11min ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 988 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9394)
     Memory: 1.1M
        CPU: 25ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─988 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Feb 08 17:16:52 svr systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Feb 08 17:16:52 svr cron[988]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Feb 08 17:16:52 svr cron[988]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Feb 08 17:16:52 svr CRON[994]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 08 17:16:52 svr CRON[996]: (root) CMD (sleep 120 /home/onboot.sh)
Feb 08 17:16:52 svr CRON[994]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 08 17:17:01 svr CRON[1063]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Feb 08 17:17:01 svr CRON[1064]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 08 17:17:01 svr CRON[1063]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

The `onboot.sh` file contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove USB module or interrupt handler conflict with NIC stops qm 100
rmmod ehci_pci
rmmod ehci_hcd
```

I've tried to move the script file to `/home`, `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin`, no luck. After 2 reboots, cron log shows:

```
Feb  8 17:08:13 svr cron[985]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Feb  8 17:08:13 svr cron[985]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Feb  8 17:08:13 svr CRON[993]: (root) CMD (sleep 120 /home/onboot.sh)
Feb  8 17:15:09 svr crontab[2206]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Feb  8 17:15:34 svr crontab[2206]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Feb  8 17:16:52 svr cron[988]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Feb  8 17:16:52 svr cron[988]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Feb  8 17:16:52 svr CRON[996]: (root) CMD (sleep 120 /home/onboot.sh)
Feb  8 17:17:01 svr CRON[1064]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

But that's it. If I run the script file normally as in `bash /home/onboot.sh`, it executes perfectly fine. Permissions for `/home/onboot.sh` are

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 150 Feb  8 17:14 /home/onboot.sh`

What obvious oversight am I making?

Comment: so the command you're running is `sleep 120 /home/onboot.sh`? try that on the command line and see what happens

Comment: No, `sleep 120` is a parameter for the cron job, where `@reboot` is the time interval, and `/home/onboot.sh` contains the commands. My intention was to have `rmmod ehci_pci; rmmod ehci_hcd; qm start 100` run 2 minutes after reboot, but I'm missing something

Comment: I've never heard of a `sleep n` "cron job parameter" - do you have any documentation that describes these cron job parameters?

Comment: Trying to find where I read it, very possible I misread something. However, I removed the sleep parameter entirely and it's the same result

Comment: Your PATH only contains `/usr/bin:/bin`, but `rmmod` is in `/sbin`. Use the full path `/sbin/rmmod`. Check your mail.

Comment: Btw [this is what I read](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/) Was I just missing the `&&` operand?

Comment: Yes, you need `&&` or `;` if you want to run multiple commands. It's shell code.

Comment: `I just missing the && operand` exactly, and of course, there's nothing called a "cron job parameter"

Comment: Rather than invoking `rmmod` why not blacklist the modules and have them not load in the first place?

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was as @Freddy said, I needed the path for `rmmod`. @roaima I tried that before, I added `ehci_pci` and `ehci_hcd` to /etc/modprobe.d/pve-blacklist.conf, after a reboot, the modules are still loaded

Comment: @JustinRiley if you have an initramfs you'd need to update that too

Comment: Alternatively, just delete the modules from `/lib/modules`.

Comment: Yeah it looks like that OP had the same problem, but his is constant. Mine only occurs when trying to pass through a PCI device to a VM in Proxmox VE. I like my approach because I can put a sleep condition on the cron job, that way if I need to use USB, there’s small window to do so. Recompiling the kernel is a rabbit hole I don’t really want to go down

Answer (score 0):

All credit to [Freddy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/332764/freddy) but the fix was to add the full path for `rmmod` to the script file, i.e `/usr/sbin/rmmod ehci_pci`